# Slow PHP/MySQL Query. Re-factor assistance requested. (160k and 300 row table lengths)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, refactoring, timeout

So I have a "notes" field that is getting one row (assigned_user_id) updated to new id's. Notes is approx. 160k in length. The users table is around 300.

For each notes row I compare the assigned_user_id to the users table, if a match is found, get the new user ID and update the notes table. Rinse repeat:

```
//dis-allow timeout. Was timing out consistently under 100 rows changes.
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);

//foreach note
$counter = 0;
foreach ( $msCRMAnnotations as $key=>$value)
{

    //foreach user, check for match between assigned_user_id and id_mscrm
    foreach( $sugarCRMUsers as $key2=>$value2 )
    {
        if($value['assigned_user_id'] == $value2['id_mscrm'] )
        {
            //give some output as to what is changing...
            echo("Note #"  . $counter++ . " - Note id " . $value['id'] . "  is assigned to user " . $value2['user_name'] . ".<br />" );

            $query = "
                UPDATE `notes`
                SET `assigned_user_id` = '" . $value2['id'] . "'
                WHERE `id` = '" . $value['id'] . "' AND
                `assigned_user_id` = '" . $value['assigned_user_id'] . "'
            ";
            $DB->query($query);
            //unset($query);
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically we are migrating select data from a MsCRM to SugarCRM. This being the accounts/notes/users phase of the project.

So now the question....how can I best re-factor the above code to be more performant? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to set indexes for these columns, for faster search

Comment: Added index on assigned_user_id and id columns (both being char(36) types per SugarCRM's requirement)...

Result: _MASSIVE_ speed increase (now able to do 7265 between timeouts)....and that is why I need to work on my SQL skills.

TYVM riwette.

Comment: If you like somebody's answer you can mark it as accepted, by clicking on the check near the anwser

Comment: Can you explain a few things? What is user table format? Are you using 2 columns in this table for old and new id, or those come from different tables? Cant this be done in database in one go  instead of having to do this for individual user? Sorry if my questions make no sense, i have no experience with any CRM, but i know some sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Assuming from comments:***

Try to set indexes for these columns, for faster search.

Answer (score 0):

Using a prepared statement *might* help. See [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
...
foreach (...) {
   $stmt->execute($params);
}
...
```

Also, you could use the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) command to issue multiple updates at once. Depending on how your primary key is implemented this may/may not work:

```
REPLACE INTO `notes` (`id`, `assigned_user_id`)
VALUES
(?, ?),
(?, ?),
(?, ?),
(?, ?),
(?, ?)
```

... you'd also need a set of parameters containing ids and assigned_user_ids.

[Edit] PDO may decide to emulate prepared statements. You can turn this off with `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE)`. Profile this both ways to see what works best for you.

Comment: yeaaa, unfort we're using mysqli over PDO for this project. I really need to exercise the use of prepared statements more. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: @Pheagey It looked like `$DB->query` might have been PDO. No worries.